# Reactjs - Moment

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

Am not able to parse the date from mongodb and render in textbox.

Mongodb date format is : `mmm dd yyyy hh mm ss a`

```
<input 
    name="date" 
    type="date" 
    disabled={ this.state.mode } 
    value={ this.state.item.date ? 
       <Moment format="DD-MMM-YYYY">{ this.state.item.date }</Moment> : null } 
    className="form-control" 
    onChange={ this.handleInputChange } />
```

Am trying with the above code. Please suggest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of moment.js library. Install it as a package dependency like

```
npm install -S moment
```

Then use it in your input like

```
<input 
name="date" 
type="date" 
disabled={ this.state.mode } 
value={ this.state.item.date ? moment(new Date(this.state.item.date)).format("DD-MMM-YYYY"): ''} 
className="form-control" 
onChange={ this.handleInputChange } />
```

DEMO:

```js
var data = 'Thu Dec 29 2011 20:14:56 GMT-0600 (CST)';
console.log(moment(new Date(data)).format("DD-MMM-YYYY"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nope., its not working.  <input name="date" type="date" disabled={ this.state.mode } value={ this.state.item.date ? moment(new Date(this.state.item.date)).format("DD-MMM-YYYY") : null } className="form-control" onChange={ this.handleInputChange } /> .. I have installed moment already

Answer (score 1):

Use the parse option like this

```
<input 
    name="date" 
    type="date" 
    disabled={ this.state.mode } 
    value={ this.state.item.date ? 
       <Moment format="DD-MMM-YYYY" parse="MMM DD YYYY hh mm ss a">{ this.state.item.date }</Moment> : null } 
    className="form-control" 
    onChange={ this.handleInputChange } />
```

Comment: I want to format the input string "mmm dd yyyy hh mm ss a" to "DD-MMM-YYYY" format and display in date field.

Comment: If mongodb is returning the date in this format "mmm dd yyyy hh mm ss a". Try adding parse="mmm dd yyyy hh mm ss a" if that doesn't work then its probably parse="MMM DD YYYY hh mm ss a".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment` npm for doing this:

```
import moment from 'moment'

<input 
   name="date" 
   type="date" 
   disabled={ this.state.mode } 
   value={ this.state.item.date ? moment(this.state.item.date).format('DD-MMM-YYYY') : null } 
   className="form-control" 
   onChange={ this.handleInputChange } />
```

You can study [here](https://momentjs.com/) for more details.

Comment: Hi , Its working in IE but not working in chrome. please help.

Comment: It should work. Check if there is any error in console.